# fortran compilation on mac osx 10.8.5

Tags: macos, compilation, homebrew, gfortran

I have a mac 10.8.5. Dont have xcode installed and dont want to install unless needed. using homebrew for installation of most packages.

1. Default gcc:
   gcc --version
   i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
2. installed latest gcc (4.9) using homebrew, using following command on terminal
   'brew install gcc'
   This installed gcc-4.9 on /usr/local/Cellar
3. Now gcc , invokes gcc-4.2 and use gcc-4.9 for invoking latest gcc.
4. I have a hello.f90 file that I need to compile using gcc using
   gfortran -o hello hello.f90
   this compiles but ./hello gives the following output:

***>>./hello

dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.9.1/libgfortran.3.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/gayathri/work/code/pythonize/fortran/./hello
  Reason: image not found

Trace/BPT trap: 5***

***I HAVE SET HOMEBREW_PREFIX TO /usr/local/Cellar***

I find the libgfortran.3.dylib in the /usr/local/Cellar... path. Why does not gfortran library get located?

My fortran code is simple hello world code:

program hello

```
  implicit none

  print *, "hello"

  end program hello
```

Comment: Can you post a gist with the output of brew config and brew doctor? You may have a bad install_name_tool.

Comment: @TimSmith Isn't `install_name_tool` installed as part of the Xcode Command line tools?

Comment: It ships with the OS, not with Xcode. Some tools like OS X GCC Installer misbehave and replace it with an older version that doesn't play nice with Homebrew. Homebrew's advice is to restore it from a system backup or a install disc.